# How to write a python code on checking an arithmetic progression?

Tags: python

Define a Python function progression(l) that takes a non-empty list of integers l and returns 
**True**: If the integers in l form an arithmetic progression
i.e, l is of the form [a,a+d,a+2d,…,a+kd].

```
>>> progression([3])  
True

>>> progression([7,3,-1,-5])  
True

>>> progression([3,5,7,9,10])  
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pair adjacent numbers, calculate the differences between the pairs, and determine that the list forms an arithmetic progression if the number of unique differences is no greater than 1:

```
from operator import sub
def progression(l):
    return len(set(sub(*p) for p in zip(l, l[1:]))) <= 1
```

so that:

```
print(progression([3]))
print(progression([7,3,-1,-5]))
print(progression([3,5,7,9,10]))
```

outputs:

```
True
True
False
```